# SQL Server 2008 : Multiple Queries in One Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 stored procedures that retrieve data from a table called `Places`. The procedures are called by C# code one at a time. These are the table columns.

```
  [ID] int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
  [Name] varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  [Latitude] decimal(18, 2) NOT NULL,
  [Longitude] decimal(18, 2) NOT NULL
```

These are the 2 stored procedures

```
CREATE procedure dbo.GetPlacesByID
    @ID int
AS
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Places
WHERE  ID = @ID
GO
```

and

```
CREATE procedure dbo.GetNearbyPlaces
    @Min_Lat decimal(18, 2),
    @Min_Lng decimal(18, 2),
    @Max_Lat decimal(18, 2),
    @Max_Lng decimal(18, 2)
AS
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Places 
WHERE Latitude BETWEEN @Min_Lat AND @Max_Lat
AND   Longitude BETWEEN @Min_Lng AND @Max_Lng
ORDER By ID ASC
GO
```

The C# application calls `GetPlacesByID` first. If a row is returned, the app takes the latitude and longitude data and calculates the `@max_Lng`, `@Min_Lng`, `@Max_Lat` and `@Max_Long` variables by adding or subtracting a constant 0.005. These variables are passed to the `GetNearbyPlaces` sp which returns nearby places and the app displays the original place plus the nearby places on a Google map.

This works fine but there are two round trips to the database which is not very efficient.
I would like to combine the two procedures into one with something like

```
create procedure dbo.GetPlaces
  @ID int
select * from  dbo.Places as Row1
where ID=@ID
if Row1 is not null
  Declare @Min_Lat decimal(18, 2),
  Declare @Min_Lng decimal(18, 2),
  Declare @Max_Lat decimal(18, 2),
  Declare @Max_Lng decimal(18, 2)

  Set @Min_Lat=Row1.Latitude - 0.005
  Set @Min_Lng=Row1.Longitude - 0.005
  Set @Max_Lat=Row1.Latitude + 0.005
  Set @Max_Lng=Row1.Longitude + 0.005

 select * from dbo.Places
 where Latitude BETWEEN @Min_Lat AND @Max_Lat
 and   Longitude BETWEEN @Min_Lng AND @Max_Lng
 ....
```

The procedure would return the original row(Row1) + all the nearby places. I'm looking for suggestions on how to accomplish this. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
CREATE procedure GetNearbyPlaces
  @Id int
AS
BEGIN
  Declare @Min_Lat decimal(18, 3)
  Declare @Min_Lng decimal(18, 3)
  Declare @Max_Lat decimal(18, 3)
  Declare @Max_Lng decimal(18, 3)

  SELECT @Min_Lat=Latitude - 0.005,
    @Min_Lng=Longitude - 0.005,
    @Max_Lat=Latitude + 0.005,
    @Max_Lng=Longitude + 0.005
  FROM Places
  WHERE Id = @Id

  SELECT *
  FROM Places 
  WHERE Latitude BETWEEN @Min_Lat AND @Max_Lat
  AND   Longitude BETWEEN @Min_Lng AND @Max_Lng
  ORDER By ID ASC

END
GO
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0e55e/1)

---

After relooking this over, another issue you could potentially be having is with DECIMAL(18,2) -- I think this needs to be DECIMAL(18,3) since you're offsetting with .005.

Here is a simpler version with a single sql statement:

```
SELECT P.*
  FROM Places P
    JOIN (
      SELECT Latitude - 0.005 Min_Lat,
        Longitude - 0.005 Min_Lng,
        Latitude + 0.005 Max_Lat,
        Longitude + 0.005 Max_Lng
      FROM Places
      WHERE Id = @Id
      ) P2 ON P.Latitude BETWEEN P2.Min_Lat AND P2.Max_Lat
          AND P.Longitude BETWEEN P2.Min_Lng AND P2.Max_Lng
  ORDER By ID ASC
```

- [Updated Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e137c/1)

Comment: Tested 1st example in app. Works like a charm. I tested the 2 example in fiddle but not in the app yet. It works in fiddle so I expect it to work in the app.Thanks **sgeddes**.

Comment: **sgeddes**, I went ahead and changed the Latitude and Longitude table columns to float data types for more decimal points which allows more accuracy. Thanks