# Is it possible to get 3 select query results by executing only one stored procedure?

Tags: t-sql

I have to display data in the following format

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
| Group Name | Description | Assigned Users | Super Groups| 
-----------------------------------------------------------
|Group1      | Blah Blah   | User1          | SPG1        |
|            |             | User2          | SPG3        |
|            |             | User3          |             |
-----------------------------------------------------------
| Group2     | More Blah   | User1          | SPG5        |
|            |             | User13         |             |
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

**Assigned users** and **Super groups** data are coming from unrelated tables. Now I wonder whether is it possible to get 3 select query results in one shot (i.e. the same procedures returns 3 results). Otherwise I'm going to query the groups and users first, get the group **IDs** then query **super groups**.

So again, Is it possible to get 3 select query results by executing only one stored procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just include 3 select statements.

If you're consuming these in .net and storing them in a DataSet you'll have 3 tables in the DataSet.

Example:

```
create procedure test
as
select 1 as res1;
select 2 as res2;
select 3 as res3

exec test
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You'll have to include the three statements in your stored procedure. Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16766078/sql-server-2008-multiple-queries-in-one-stored-procedure).